# New allocates too much memory

Tags: c++, c, char, new-operator

I am writing simple function for merging two C-strings. While trying to dynamically alocate new chunk of memory i found out that :

```
char * out = new char[size];
std::cout << strlen(out) <<std::endl;
```

Returns 16 when size is 4 and 40 when size is 22 and so on.
Does anyone have an idea why it acts like that and how to allocate memory for c-string with certain number of chars?

Comment: You don't initialize the string. `strlen()` needs a 0-terminated buffer. Asked so many times...

Comment: Yup - as soon as I see strlen() in a question....

Comment: It is not clear this is a duplicate of the proposed original. That question involved applying `strlen` to an array that was initialized but that did not containing a terminating null character. This question applies `strlen` to an array that is not initialized. It is not clear from the question whether the confusion is about how `strlen` operates or about whether and how `new` initializes an array allocated this way.

Comment: @H2CO3 - like I read SO for my whole free time and know that. The issue was problem with allocation, but lack of string terminator. It is just one of simple things that just get out of your head because you are not using it for long time. And it always suprised me - how SoftDev guys can gain such a butthurt while asked simple question . Good advice -  If it hurts your soul too much and you are going to express just how much it does , instead of giving real answer - just don't do it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Right, do you have a better dupe? I am pretty confident this is a duplicate.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - but it is very clear when you look at the topic.

Comment: @pawels1991 That's why I didn't write an answer, but a comment.

Comment: @H2CO3 And express a butthurt.

Comment: That's why std::string was invented

Comment: @Neil because std::string was invented i forgot how use c-strings ;)

Answer (score 5):

The allocated memory is not initialized.  `strlen()` just keeps charging through memory until it encounters a null character (`'\0'`).  Since you have not initialized the memory pointed to by `out`, the contents of this memory are undefined, and therefore so is the behavior of `strlen()`.

`strlen()` **does not** measure the size of an allocation, so your interpretation that `new` is allocating too much memory is incorrect simply because the tool you are using to measure the size of the allocation doesn't do that at all.

In your case, `strlen()` is reading beyond the boundary of this allocation.  In this circumstance, the result could be a "wrong" value (as you see here) or your program could simply crash.

Comment: `new` initializes some objects it creates and not others, so it might be useful to explain why this allocation does not initialize the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

Using `new` to allocate memory does not initialize the memory:

```
char * out = new char[size];

// Add this code to initialize out
memset(out,'A',size-1);
out[size-1]='\0';

std::cout << strlen(out) <<std::endl;
```

Comment: Technically, `new char[size]()` is still using `new` and does.

Comment: It's just the fragment of code . After that i have a for-loop that puts exact number (equal to variable 'size') of chars into  'out' char * . And for example - instead of having 'aabb' string i have 'aabbrrrrzzzzzzzz'

Comment: @pawels1991, Are any of them a null terminator?

Comment: @pawels1991, at the very least, the last one?

Comment: Nope . So i should put NULL terminatore at the end of it ?

Comment: @pawels1991 Not NULL, but rather `'\0'`.

Comment: No, you should put a 0 or '\0' to terminate the end of it and it better be no farther than out[size-1]

Comment: @pawels1991, You'd be better off finding a book or C string tutorial than piecing together code.

Comment: NULL works fine as well :)

Comment: Using NULL for 0 may compile with your compiler, but it is absolutely the wrong thing to use semantically. NULL represents a NULL pointer, not a NUL terminator.